# Is $U=\{(r,s,t)|r,s,t \in \mathbb{R}, -r+3s+2t=0\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is $U=\{(r,s,t)|r,s,t \in \mathbb{R}, -r+3s+2t=0\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

So far all I know is that the zero vector is in the subspace. How would I go about checking if it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition?

I usually try a few examples to make sure that the three conditions for a subspace hold, but the extra condition at the end is throwing me off.

Comment: Let $u = (r_1, s_1, t_1)$ and $v = (r_2, s_2, t_2)$ be any two elements of $U$, and $a$ be any real number.  If you write out the sum $u + v$ and the product $au$ in terms of the coordinates $r_1, r_2, ...$, can you check whether they satisfy the equation defining $U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution: suppose we have $\vec x = (r,s,t)\in U, \vec y = (r',s',t')\in U$, and $k \in \mathbb R$.  Now, consider the vector 
$$
\vec v = \vec x + k \vec y = (r+kr',s+ks',t+kt')
$$
How can we show that $v$ is a member of $U$?

> Hint: note that $$-(r+kr')+3(s+ks')+2(t+kt') = (-r+3s+2t)+k(-r'+3s'+2t')$$

Now, plug in $k=1$ to get closure under addition and $\vec x = \vec 0$ to get closure under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very very lazy solution just to add something different to the much better other answer(s). The vanishing locus of a linear equation is a plane. A plane through the origin is a subspace. So yes indeed this is a subspace.

If you like to think more linear algebraically, think of the operator $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^1$ sending $(r,s,t)$ to $-r+3s+2t$. This is a linear transformation, and so its null space is a subspace. Its kernel being precisely the set $U$.

Comment: What is kernel?

Comment: Sorry, Kernel is fancy speak for null space or "subspace where the map is zero". Its a very general statement that the places where a linear transformation is zero form a subspace. This is a good thing to try and work through (and will of course show you what you need in the specific case above).

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks.